# Want to encode the value of password in some expected format

Tags: javascript, encryption, encoding, base64

We have a flex application and ANgular application,
I am doing the encryption for the value of password field but it's not getting encrypted as expected. Service code is the same for both flex as well as in ANgular.

My Expectation - I want to encrypt string `'aa'` so that I should get `3528` as an encrypted value. Sounds weird that is the requirement. Let me clarify this more.

I have the encrypting method which takes the string and key then return the encoded value as mentioned above.

```
let str1 = 'aa';

let pass1 = this._encryptionService.encryptedEncodedString(str1, this.key);

console.log("pass1 correct value should be for aa is 3528 - ", pass1); 
result in console is   W3Q= but i need 3528
```

My Angular/javascript code for encryptedEncodedString method -

```
constructor() {
    this.Base64 = require('hi-base64');

    this.key = 'some value';
    this.hgDsl = "some value";                   
}        

byteXor(source, key) {
    var result = new Array(source.length);
    var iLength = source.length;
    var iKeyLength = key.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < iLength; i++) {         
        result[i] = (source[i] ^ key.charCodeAt(i % iKeyLength));            
    }
    return result;
}

encryptUI(content, key) {
    var byteRetValue = bytesConversionUtil.convertStringToBytes(content);        

    byteRetValue = this.byteXor(byteRetValue, this.hgDsl);
    byteRetValue = this.byteXor(byteRetValue, key.toLowerCase());
    console.log("encryptUI  byteRetValue ", byteRetValue);
    return byteRetValue;
}


encryptedEncodedString(password, key){ // in flex they are using this
    var encryptedPasswordByteArr = this.encryptUI(password, key);
    var encryptedPasswordStr = bytesConversionUtil.convertBytesToString(encryptedPasswordByteArr);      
    console.log("encryptedPasswordStr ", encryptedPasswordStr);
    var encodedPassword = this.Base64.encode(encryptedPasswordStr);
    return encodedPassword;
}
```

After doing this I am getting the encoded value as -   `W3Q=` how I can convert this so I will get `3528` which is expected. I tried to do utf8 base 64 encode and then ASCII encoding but no luck.

Please guide if I have to do anything.

Comment: so its working in your flex but not in angular?

Comment: @karthick yes, correct. we converted flex code in angular javascript code and we covered all the methods but its not working.

Comment: Can you post the flex code as well. After seeing your required output, I dont think base64 is the final process.will always have alphanumberic characters plus (+,/,=). So please post the flex code

Comment: Applying XOR to two bytes and then base64 encoding you won't get *3528* in any case. Maybe you could describe algorithm how would you expect the result from the input *aa*